Undeclared Identifier `_disableInitializers();`
I got this error:
Error (7576): Undeclared identifier.
  --> src/BoxV1.sol:32:9:
   |
32 |         _disableInitializers();

When I tried to run this code:
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MI
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import {UUPSUpgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/UUPSUpgradeable.sol";
import {Initializable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/proxy/utils/Initializable.sol";
import {OwnableUpgradeable} from "@openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/access/OwnableUpgradeable.sol";

contract BoxV1 is
    Initializable,
    UUPSUpgradeable,
    OwnableUpgradeable
{
    uint256 internal number;
    
    /// @custom:oz-upgrades-unsafe-allow constructor
    constructor() {
        _disableInitializers();
    }

    function initialize(address initialOwner) public initializer {
        __Ownable_init(initialOwner);
        __UUPSUpgradeable_init();
    }

    function getNumber() external view returns (uint256) {
        return number;
    }

    function version() external pure returns (uint256) {
        return 1;
    }

    function _authorizeUpgrade(address newImplementation) internal override {}
}

I've installed the v4.5.0 version of Openzeppelin.

As you can see in this post on the Openzeppelin forum:

_disableInitializers() was added in Contracts v4.6.0 as part of the reinitializers support.

So, you need to install and use Openzeppelin v4.6.0 or above.

Hey, I installed it but it keeps showing the same error

Are you installing it in your Hardhat project using npm or yarn? If yes, then make sure that you're installing the @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable package.

You should try uninstalling it first using npm uninstall @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable or yarn remove @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable. Then, install it using npm install @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable  or yarn add @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable. It will install the latest version of the same i.e., 5.0.1 currently.

I am using foundry

I tried to use git rm @openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable but it is not working

I got this
Cloning into 'C:/Users/HP FOLIO/foundry-f23/foundry-upgrades-f24/lib/contracts-upgradeable'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable/' not found
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/openzeppelin/contracts-upgradeable' into submodule path 'C:/Users/HP FOLIO/foundry-f23/foundry-upgrades-f24/lib/contracts-upgradeable' failed
Error: git submodule exited with code 128```

Sorry, in case of foundry, the command should be forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts-upgradeable --no-commit.

It worked, thanks. Please, check DM on X

Please, check DM on X
